# JQuery Hide table row on ajax post result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code. It is supposed to hide a row on success of the onClick function. Unfortunately it just does not hide anything. I have seen this question on SO, tried the solutions with no effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteMsg(row,msgId) {
        //window.alert("deleteMsg(" + msgId + ")");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/ArcheryScoresV3/profile.jsp",
            data: { cmd:"delete_msg",
                s_token:"dn1ejdmj0dkmgerbm481adkjt0",
                message: msgId },  
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg, status, jqXHR){
                if(msg.success == "true") {
                window.alert("successfull, hiding " + row.id);
                //$(this).parents("tr").hide();
                //$(row).hide();
                row.css("background-color", "red");
            } else {
                window.alert("unsuccessfull");
            }
            },            
            error: function(xhr,status,error){
                window.alert("error, status:" + error);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
     <tr id="row1">
        <td><span onClick="deleteMsg($('row1'),'0ed71375-226e-49ae-aa14-00fbb1f7ed11');" 
                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

The alert on success shows up, so the code is being executed but I never see anything disappear or even change color. All the commented variants have been tried without success. There must be some basic misunderstanding ..

Comment: if you want get by id you must use $('#row1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your selector is wrong. `onclick = "deleteMsg($('#row1')`, )"
you forgot the little '#'

Comment: Like I thought .. something basic.. like $('row1') instead of $('#row1')
Works like charm now..

Comment: I would still like to know why all the other stuff like $(this).closest('tr') is not working. Seems like this is not what I expect it to be. To which element would this point in the deleteMsg function?

Comment: 'this' always gives the 'context' its called from, here the object invoking the method is your 'span', hence 'this' should be referring to 'span'. I can't say for sure why $(this) didn't work, ideally it should. Take a console.log of 'this' in your successCallback. If possible create a fiddle for this. Will see. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `#` in your Jquery selector :

```
<tr id="row1">
    <td>
        <span onClick="deleteMsg($('#row1'),'0ed71375-226e-49ae-aa14-00fbb1f7ed11');" 
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
        </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And then, you can use `row.hide();` in your `success` function to hide the block (and not `$(row).hide();` like you tried)